# Using encode PostgreSQL function together with pg node.js module

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I'm trying to write a query that will insert a user along with a salted hashed password into my table. The query I use to do this from the command line in postgresql is the following:

```sql
INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, salt) VALUES (someName, someEmail, encode(sha256(CONCAT('somePw','mySalt')::bytea), 'base64'), 'mySalt');
```

This works perfectly well. Now I'm trying to call this query from node.js using the pg module, but it doesn't work. When I do the following (so wrapping the query in double quotation marks "" so I can wrap the base64 keyword in single quotation marks ''), I get an error:

```js
const pg = require('pg');
const Pool = pg.Pool;
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'foo',
    host: 'localhost',
    database: 'bar',
    password: 'password',
    port: 5432,
});

pool.query("INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, salt) VALUES ($1, $2, encode(sha256(CONCAT($3,$4)::bytea), 'base64'), $4) ", [name.toString(), email.toString(), password.toString(), getSalt().toString()], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
}


// error: could not determine data type of parameter $4
```

So I tried using the single quotation marks '' for the query and using the escaped version ('') for the base64 keyword, but that does not work either and gives the same error:

```js
pool.query('INSERT INTO users (name, email, password, salt) VALUES ($1, $2, encode(sha256(CONCAT($3,$4)::bytea), \'base64\'), $4) ', [name.toString(), email.toString(), password.toString(), getSalt().toString()], (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
            throw error
        }
}


// error: could not determine data type of parameter $4
```

Putting the base64 keyword in no quotation marks does not work either, that yields the error

```
Error: column "base64" does not exist
```

Does anyone know what the correct way of posing this query in pg is? Thanks!

Comment: Try casting with `$4::text`.  It's not the `'base64'` that's causing your first error message.

Comment: Great Idea & worked, thank you @MikeOrganek! Almost feel stupid for not coming up with that myself, haha. If you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you, but this was more on the typo end of things, and all I provided was a fresh set of eyes :-)  Good luck!